# Verify that the Kernel Path Interpreter is Correct

Tags: python-2.7, enthought, canopy

I am having a problem starting Canopy.

I was running a large calculation when I restarted the kernel.

Ever since then I have not been able to get Canopy to open to the editor. When I open the program, The `'Welcome to Canopy'` window opens but when I try to open an editor or a recent file I get the following error:

*"The kernel (user python environment) has failed to start. Please verify that the kernel interpreter path is correct."*

I have tried closing and opening Canopy.

Shutting my computer down and starting Canopy.

Uninstalling and re-installing Canopy (I started with 1.1 and this time downloaded 1.2)
And followed the directions at https://support.enthought.com/entries/23097479-Restarting-Canopy-after-Unexpected-error-ParseError-

When I click on the Show Details button in the error window, it says:

```
Error message:
[Error 740] The requested operation required elevation
```

How can I get Canopy up and running again? Or are there other environment better than Canopy for free download?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a new one! Are you by chance running Windows Vista? If not, which Windows version? Are you still logged in as the same user that you were before the original crash? Any other changes that you have made in the system configuration?

I suggest that you delete the following directories

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Enthought
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
```

then restart Canopy. When it asks you, accept its default locations for the environment path.

Note that to see the AppData directory in Windows Explorer, you must set Explorer to show hidden files (Computer / Organize / Folder & Search Options / View / Advanced settings / Show hidden...)

Answer (score 0):

For the better than canopy part of your question, try Anaconda it's put out by Travis Oliphant, formerly of Enthought, and creator of NumPy and SciPy ... and it's awesome.  It comes with Numba, which nearly eliminates the need for Cython or writing c-extensions in general.  For your first question, I have no experience with canaopy other than frustration so I am no help.

Anaconda can be downloaded for free [here](http://continuum.io)